# Passing variables to template based on db

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to add a feature to my app that would allow me to enable/disable the "Call Me" button based on whether or not I am at [home|the office]. I created a model in the database called setting, it looks like this:

```
class setting(models.Model): 
    key = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Pretty simple. There is currently one row, available, the value of it is the string True. I want to be able to transparently pass variables to the templates like this:

```
{% if available %}
   <!-- Display button -->
{% else %}
   <!-- Display grayed out button -->
{% endif %}
```

Now, I could add logic to every view that would check the database, and pass the variable to the template, but I am trying to stay [DRY](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself).

What is the best way to do this?

**UPDATE**
I created a context processor, and added it's path to the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, but it is not being passed to the template

```
def available(request):
available = Setting.objects.get(key="available")
if open.value == "True":
    return {"available":True}
else:
    return {}
```

**UPDATE TWO**
If you are using the shortcut render_to_response, you need to pass an instance of RequestContext to the function.

from the [django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext):

> If you're using Django's render_to_response() shortcut to populate a template with the contents of a dictionary, your template will be passed a Context instance by default (not a RequestContext). To use a RequestContext in your template rendering, pass an optional third argument to render_to_response(): a RequestContext instance. Your code might look like this:

```
def some_view(request):
     # ...
     return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                               my_data_dictionary,
                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Many thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a [custom context processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

Comment: Context processors are *the best ever*. That sounds childish, but they're so useful. I use a context processor I wrote myself in order to pass a user's facebook profile information to every template. Because it's a very simple function, that only returns a dictionary, it's quite simple to implement. Just remember to set it *and* the default context processors (because if you change it, it'll be unset) in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.

Comment: So, just add TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS to settings.py?

Comment: @George 'Griffin: Yes, and add the path to your custom processor.

Comment: I seem to have hit a snag. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to pass the RequestContext instance in the view for the template context processors to be processed.  Read through the section titled "When context processors are applied" in the aforementioned docs (and the sample code below it.)

Comment: I just realized that. I was using the shortcut render_to_response. I am going to update my question.